# Polynomial interpolation of a polynomial with degree at most $n$ with $n$ data points is same as polynomial

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I'm trying to solve following question from D Kincaid & W Cheney, Numerical Analysis section 6.2 and need a proof check

> Prove that if $p$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$ then
>
> $$ p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} p[x_0,\dots,x_i] \prod_{j=0}^{i-1}(x-x_j). $$

My attempt to solve this is using the uniqueness of interpolation polynomial of degree $n$,
since we have a polynomial with degree at most $n$ and we are using $n+1$ data points to interpolate that polynomial we get a polynomial with degree at most $n$ so now we have two polynomials with degree at most $n$ and they both interpolate same points so they most be the same.

Comment: Is the notation $p[x_0,\ldots,x_i]$ meant to reference divided differences? You seem to be just restating what it means for a property to guarantee a unique polynomial.  What exactly needs verification?

Comment: Yes it's divided differences. I might understand the question wrong. my understanding is the question is to prove if we write polynomial interpolation for a polynomial with degree at most n using n+1 data points the result will be the same polynomial.

Comment: Two polynomials of degree at most $n$ which agree at $n+1$ distinct arguments ("data points") will certainly be equal.  But taking that as a known result, the bulk of your solution should be devoted to proving those two polynomials in fact agree at $n+1$ distinct arguments (presumably at $x_0,\ldots,x_n$).

Comment: You are right but in the book that is proved as a theorem so I think I can use it as a fact for this problem.

Comment: The uniqueness follows from the polynomials $\prod_{j=0}^{i-1}(x-x_j)$ having degree exactly $j-1$. One easy way to prove the formula is by noting [how divided differences behave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences#Properties) with respect to addition of a constant and multiplication. Do the case of a constant polynomial and note that a polynomial $p$ of degree $n$ can be written as $p(x)=(x-x_{n-1})q(x)+p[x_{n-1}]$. Then you apply Leibniz's rule to compute $((x-x_{n-1})q(x))[x_0,x_1,...,x_i]$ and assume that $q$ satisfies your formula by induction.

Comment: Another advantage of proving it this way, is that you get to see the analogy between this formula and Taylor series $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{f^{(i)}(0)}{i!}x^i$, which you can prove exactly in the same way, by inductively taking $k$ derivatives, for $k=0,1,...,n$ and evaluating the result at $x=0$. In your formula one takes divided differences instead, which shift and evaluate at the new point $x_n$.

Comment: @hardmath in the question it did not stated distinct data points about $x_0, \dots, x_n$ is this something presumed in these questions?

Comment: Yes, since if we try to count the same point $x_0$ more than once the interpolation property fails (as does the definition of divided differences).  How many times should we allow the same point to be counted?  If you want to apply interpolation with a repeated $x_0$, one way is to consider not only the same value of the polynomials, but (for example) the same value of derivatives.  But this is a digression.

Comment: @hardmath I don't think so, the fact you point out in the comments  "proving those two polynomials in fact agree at $n+1$ distinct arguments" and the uniqueness that plop stated is the answer.

Comment: We seem to be talking past each other.  The hard part is showing the divided differences version of a polynomial agrees with the original version at all points $x_0,\ldots,x_n$, and the details of that were covered in the earlier Question.